# Twitter starem API not giving any output or error

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to create a social application based on hashtags of twitter. My aim is to find how many tweets, how many users, top ten tweets users, top ten influencing tweets based on no of re tweets or interactions using Twitter live stream API for a Hashtag.

So i created twitter application and i am able to login, able to get user timeline and tweets of user. But i am not able to work with live stream API. I am posting my code below about how i am trying to access tweets related to a hashtag.

```
$data = $connection->post('https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=15&track=Rajpal Yadav');
```

Where $connection is working fine i tested it.

Answer (score -1):

Try out new Twitter API from https://dev.twitter.com. This document explains how to use Embedded Tweets on your website, and also how developers can integrate Embedded Tweets in to their applications through their new API.

Comment: this is not my answer i know there are new API's